# How to define new loops in algorithmicx?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

How can I define a new loop in algorithmicx? For example, code like this:

ex1)

PreLoop s do

--statement1

--statement2

ex2)

PostLoop s do

--statement1

--statement2

Is it possible to define it as a command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You might have a look to [our start page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436): it will help you to familiarize with the site.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done using the `\algdef` command. This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algdef{SE}{PreLoop}{EndPreLoop}[1]{\textbf{preloop} \(\mbox{#1}\) \textbf{do}}{\textbf{end}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\PreLoop{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndPreLoop\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

For more information, see the algorithmicx manual, e.g., http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf .